# How to resize a cylinder from one end and move it backwards in Roblox

Tags: lua, 3d, physics, roblox, tween

I'm making a *cigarette* in Roblox and I want it to work correctly

it made the *cig* resize to the front.

you can get it yourself here:
https://filetransfer.io/data-package/qKBHvHxS#link

and for people who want the code all you really need to see is this:

```
for i = bit.Size.X, 0, -0.1 do
    local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(0.1)
    local goal = {}
    goal.Size = Vector3.new(i, bit.Size.Y, bit.Size.Z)
    local tween = TweenService:Create(bit, tweenInfo, goal)
    tween:Play()
    wait(0.1)
    bit.CFrame = bit.CFrame + bit.CFrame.LookVector * -0.1
end
```

But seriously, I do recommend downloading the RBXM file and actually testing it.

Also its a tool, so this accounts for rotations.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that it might get you banned unless you have a verified 18+ account and mark the game as 18+

Comment: +Buzzyy, this is a custom thing for me and my friends, so I hope it doesn't get me banned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use a Tween, don't put it into a for-loop. When two Tweens try to manipulate the same properties, they start to cancel each other out.

So just put all the resizing logic into one tween and make it take the full length of time :

```lua
local BURN_RATE = 1.0 -- studs/second
local cigLength = bit.Size.X
local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(cigLength * BURN_RATE) -- take more time based on how long the cig is

local goal = {
    Size = Vector3.new(0, bit.Size.Y, bit.Size.Z),
    Position = (bit.Position - Vector3.new(cigLength / 2, 0, 0)),
}
local tween = TweenService:Create(bit, tweenInfo, goal)
tween:Play()

-- TODO : if the tool is put away, simply cancel the tween
```